# Redgate SQL Search - How can you search for exact phrases with symbols?

Tags: sql, redgate

How can you search for the following exact phrase in SQL Search please?  I've tried using 'Match whole words only' and it doesn't find anything.  I manually confirmed I have 2 stored procedures with the phrase I'm looking for, but SQL Search won't bring them up.

When I uncheck 'Match whole words only', it will bring the two SP's up, but every word in the search and every plus in the SP is highlighted separately.  The expected behavior is to only have the phrase I typed in the search highlighted in the viewer.  As it is I have to visually scan the SP and piece together if it meets the criteria.  (I know it's not a major issue, just trying to learn the functionality of the software.)

Is this possible in SQL Search and if so, how would I do it please?

Thank you.

```
@Records_Added + 'Records
```